# SQL Server 2017 remote connection error - 40 on GCP

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform

I'm getting SQL error 40 when I try to connect to remote SQL using SQL management studio from my local system. It connects without any error when I switch my wifi to another network but it shows SQL error 40 from my office internet connection. I used to connect earlier from the office too. I've checked multiple networks and it throws the same connection error 40 on some other internet connections too. I've tried using the IP address instead of domain name on those networks but no luck. I've also checked the port on firewall, TCP IP, Named pipes everything is up to the mark. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Error on some internet connection:

[image]

Connects fine from other internet connection:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a routing or Firewall issue on the troublesome network. It may possibly something to do with a dynamic IP address if it worked earlier on that network.

You need to speak to whoever manages the network on which you are getting the error and ask them to investigate.